# How to change syntax coloring for a Qt pro file in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, qt, syntax-highlighting

I'm using a dark background...

Answer (score 1):

What I have found so far is that you can go to window->preferences->content types and add .pro and .pri as content type make file. This works about half of the time...